# GCM demo server sending message to device raises 401 error

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, tomcat

As many other newbies to java and android i'm trying to run gcm demo server and gcm demo client on windows, using eclipse to run vertual device and tomcat as a webserer.

I have no problems with registering and unregestering device but i got an error 401 when trying to send a message. Read a lot answers on similar questions but still don't have a clue what i'm doing wrong. I put apy key, server url and sender id in places mentioned in tutorial. Also changed code in SendAllMessagesServlet.java a bit:

```
// Processes the request to add a new message.  
@Override protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
    List<String> devices = Datastore.getDevices();
    String status;
    if (devices.isEmpty()) {
        status = "Message ignored as there is no device registered!";
    } else {
        // NOTE: check below is for demonstration purposes; a real application
        // could always send a multicast, even for just one recipient
        // MY CODE
        String collapseKey = "mycollapsekey";
        String userMessage = "testmessage";
        // END OF MY CODE
        if (devices.size() == 1) {
            // send a single message using plain post
            String registrationId = devices.get(0);
            //  Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
            //  BELOW I HAVE CHANGED MESSAGE BUILDING A BIT:
            Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .collapseKey(collapseKey)
                .timeToLive(30)
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("message", userMessage)
                .build();
            Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, 5);
            status = "Sent message to one device: " + result;
        } else {
            // send a multicast message using JSON
            // must split in chunks of 1000 devices (GCM limit)
            int total = devices.size();
            List<String> partialDevices = new ArrayList<String>(total);
            int counter = 0;
            int tasks = 0;
            for (String device : devices) {
                counter++;
                partialDevices.add(device);
                int partialSize = partialDevices.size();
                if (partialSize == MULTICAST_SIZE || counter == total) {
                    asyncSend(partialDevices);
                    partialDevices.clear();
                    tasks++;
                }
            }
            status = "Asynchronously sending " + tasks + " multicast messages to " + total + " devices";
        }
    }
    req.setAttribute(HomeServlet.ATTRIBUTE_STATUS, status.toString());
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home").forward(req, resp);
}
```

But I still get next error when sending message, here is my tomcat localhost log file:

```
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.apache.webapp.balancer.BalancerFilter: init(): ruleChain: [org.apache.webapp.balancer.RuleChain: [org.apache.webapp.balancer.rules.URLStringMatchRule: Target string: News / Redirect URL: http://www.cnn.com], [org.apache.webapp.balancer.rules.RequestParameterRule: Target param name: paramName / Target param value: paramValue / Redirect URL: http://www.yahoo.com], [org.apache.webapp.balancer.rules.AcceptEverythingRule: Redirect URL: http://jakarta.apache.org]]
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
окт 22, 2012 1:07:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet SendAllMessagesServlet threw exception
com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:177)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:93)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:881)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:541)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Stderr log:

```
2012-10-22 13:06:37 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
окт 22, 2012 1:06:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;c:\ant\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib;;.
окт 22, 2012 1:06:38 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
окт 22, 2012 1:06:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 531 ms
окт 22, 2012 1:06:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
окт 22, 2012 1:06:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.36
окт 22, 2012 1:06:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
INFO: XML validation disabled
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive gcm-demo.war
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.ApiKeyInitializer contextInitialized
INFO: Reading /api.key from resources (probably from WEB-INF/classes
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/32  config=null
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
INFO: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
окт 22, 2012 1:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1219 ms
окт 22, 2012 1:06:58 PM com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.Datastore register
INFO: Registering APA91bF0kArKvvJsHu4qS92FQl-CLKt0CJL8_SrtyL9OkGSqQQUMywMvPhulG4xmdiX_uVhdXs6xERY5pwQzHES-aI-tBCOgMZ_JOBT8S_RIK9XhyQDf49Yfr9g4nSnfgN2GIJHlnqTA4mAJBolnjfuQKLmULl0g5g
```

What I've missed or where to read more on such a problems solving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just answered a similar question - [accessing /gcm-demo/sendAll. Reason: HTTP Status Code: 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009851/accessing-gcm-demo-sendall-reason-http-status-code-401/13010363#13010363)

Check the sender API key that you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just checked my sender API key. I'm using  Key for server apps (with IP locking). I put my server ip in form and the key seems to be correct but i still got errors. Maybe i have changed code not in place where it should be? Where exactly i have to put construction Sender sender = new Sender(MY_KEY);?

Comment: What other errors do you get ? Does the 401 problem still occur ? There is no specific place to instantiate the constructor. You can instantiate it before sending a GCM request.

Comment: I put Sender sender = new Sender("MY_KEY"); into doPost, before sending message, now i got:  HTTP Status 500, com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401
 com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:177)
 com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
 com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:94)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

Comment: Thank you, Deepak Bala. The reason was in api key as you mentioned. Changed api and messages are sent without problems. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool. Please accept the answer so others will find it when they come across the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this error too,

[image]

turns out i hadn't enabled `Google Cloud Messaging for Android`. (On one of my machines, this was automatically enabled while following the same steps, don't know why it didn't do same on the other) Long story short, go to developers console and enable it.

`APIs and Auths | APIs | Google Cloud Messaging for Android`

refresh your browser and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not addressed well on any of the forum may be because it has multiple causes. 
My case was: I was doing a demo of GCM push notifications and it worked the first time. But as I proceeded
next day with same code i found the exception mention in the answer. On observation, I noticed that my public
IP had changed as it is not static. This IP has to be provided when you create project on google developers
console. You can find your public IP by searching "my public IP address" in google. Or for demo purpose i
would now strongly recommend you to use IP as 0.0.0.0/0 which is recommended and when you deploy your project,
your server IP would be static. You can then replace 0.0.0.0/0 IP with your server IP.
Also, check all the keys like 'project number' and 'server API key'.
Hope it helps. CHEERS :)

Answer (score 0):

> Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized

If any one is getting this above error try check your jvm.dll path default path located is *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll* change it to the right path.